# converting .c module to .o module

Tags: kernel, compiling, modules

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and the installed kernel for driver programming. In [rubini's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672325128) it is mentioned to create a `.o` file from a `.c` file, but I'm not getting it.
it uses `obj-m := eg_drv1.o`, but when I try and build the `.c` file I get this:

`error: make: *** No targets.  Stop.`

I'm completely confused.
First question I have is how do I convert a `.c` file to `.o` file and then to `.ko` file to use the module?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice article about 'Compile Linux kernel modules' http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html

Just go through it. It contains an example just give it a try.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**:  I have just tried and found that copy and paste is not working. I have to manually enter the contents of Makefile to work it out. Anyway it works fine. Just try and let us know the result.

Comment: The issue with copy/paste and Makefiles is that makefile rules lines must start with \t (tabs), when you use copy/paste from the web those tabs are pasted as spaces breaking the syntax.

Comment: @João Pinto: Yes you are absolutely right.